# gathering info from macos signed app bundle

Tags: macos, certificate, bundle

on Mac Os X what is the preferred way to get info about the developer that signed a bundle? i.e. if i receive an app bundle that does comply with gatekeeper policies, how do i see who is the developer/producer etc?
The app is not distributed from app store.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic method would be something such as:

```
codesign -dvvv /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

> -d, --display |
>                Display information about the code at the path(s) given.
>
> -v, --verbose |
>                Sets (with a numeric value) or increments the verbosity level of
>                output.

More Information: x-man-page://codesign